# Error while creating person group person in microsoft cognitive face API

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

I have a code which uses older API. I don't know new API. Those who know help me with modifying the code.

```
import cognitive_face as CF
from global_variables import personGroupId
import sqlite3

Key = '###################'
CF.Key.set(Key)
BASE_URL = 'https://region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/' 
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)

if len(sys.argv) is not 1:
    res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))    #error line
    print(res)
    extractId = str(sys.argv[1])[-2:]
    connect = sqlite3.connect("studentdb")
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE id = " + extractId
    cursor = connect.execute(cmd)
    isRecordExist = 0
    for row in cursor:                                                          
        isRecordExist = 1
    if isRecordExist == 1:                                                      
        connect.execute("UPDATE Students SET personID = ? WHERE ID = ?",(res['personId'], extractId))
    connect.commit()                                                            
    connect.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using older API. You are expected to use the new API. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python-sdk) (official documentation) for installing the package and further reference.

**PACKAGE:**

`pip install --upgrade azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face`

Import the following libraries (excluding other basic libraries)

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models import TrainingStatusType, Person, SnapshotObjectType, OperationStatusType
```

**The updated API command is as follows:**

`res = face_client.person_group_person.create(person_group_id, str(sys.argv[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Soorya answered above, For those who want the sample code reference, you can see the latest API sample code from [`here`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code)

```
def build_person_group(client, person_group_id, pgp_name):
    print('Create and build a person group...')
    # Create empty Person Group. Person Group ID must be lower case, alphanumeric, and/or with '-', '_'.
    print('Person group ID:', person_group_id)
    client.person_group.create(person_group_id = person_group_id, name=person_group_id)
```